# Why does Gradle always call an ant task first?

Tags: ant, gradle

I use the OWASP Dependency Check from its ant task (no Gradle support yet) like this:

```
task checkDependencies() {
    ant.taskdef(name: 'checkDependencies',
        classname: 'org.owasp.dependencycheck.taskdefs.DependencyCheckTask',
        classpath: 'scripts/dependency-check-ant-1.2.5.jar')
    ant.checkDependencies(applicationname: "MyProject",
        reportoutputdirectory: "generated",
        dataDirectory: "generated/dependency-check-cache") {
        fileset(dir: 'WebContent/WEB-INF/lib') {
            include(name: '**.jar')
        }
    }
}
```

This works way too good. Even though nothing defines this ant task as dependency (neither in ant nor in Gradle), it is always executed first, even for a simple `gradlew tasks`. Why is that and how can I avoid this? (The dependency check is quite slow.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *very* common confusion with Gradle. In your example above you are executing the Ant tasks during project **configuration**. What you really intended was for it to run during task **execution**. To fix this, your execution logic should be placed within a **task action**, either by using a `doLast {...}` configuration block or using the left shift (`<<`) operator.

```
task checkDependencies << {
    // put your execution logic here
}
```

See the [Gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases) for more information about the Gradle build lifecycle.